# Terragrunt inputs seemingly ignored

Tags: terraform, terragrunt

I recently started working with Terraform and Terragrunt as a project for my company:

Our repo provides the following working tree:

```
netbox-devices
L-----github
L-----dev
L-----example
L-----prod
```

We are only using this structure as reference as we are **not** separating environments and prod is the "only" actual work directory, I am working on the structure for site 2, the structure of site 1 is a working structure example, that being said:

```
prod/
├── env.tfvars
├── site1
│   ├── 200_site1_netbox_devices
│   │   └── terragrunt.hcl
│   └── env.tfvars
└── site2
    ├── 113_site2_netbox_devices
    │   ├── common
    │   │   └── defaults.hcl
    │   ├── pc1.hcl
    │   └── terragrunt.hcl
    ├── env.tfvars
    └── terragrunt.hcl
```

My "issue" is that the terragrunt.hcl has many repeated values and I need to register around a 100 hosts for site2. Since about 60% of the values are repeated I am positive this is not DRY.

Furthermore I noticed that this project is part of a workflow, the definitions for the "device" object (the 100 I need to add) are located in variables.tf file **external** to the structure above and has the following structure:

```
variable "devices" {
  description = "The list of devices to be provisioned"
  type = list(object({
    device_type_id = number,
    name           = string,
    role_id        = number
    site_id        = number
    cluster_id     = optional(number)
    comments       = optional(string),
    custom_fields  = optional(map(any)),
    description    = optional(string),
    location_id    = optional(number),
    platform_id    = optional(number),
    rack_face      = optional(string),
    rack_id        = optional(number),
    rack_position  = optional(number),
    serial_number  = optional(string),
    status         = optional(string),
    tags           = optional(set(string))
    tenant_id      = optional(number)
  }))
  default = []
}
```

I am not allowed to modify the above.

I started to try to come with a way to set "defaults" to the inputs located in the deepest terragrunt.hcl of the site2 structure, for which I created the rest of the files:

pc1.hcl (this is supposed to be my default template)

```
locals{
        description                     = "This is a baremetal server"
        device_type_id                  = 1
        role_id                         = 2        
        site_id                         = 113       # 
        tags                            = ["infra"]

        rack_face                       = "front"

        custom_fields = {
            env                         = "prod"
            consul_datacenter           = "site2-prod"
            vm_provider                 = "local"

            vm_env                      = "prod"
            vm_site                     = "site1"
            vm_vpc                      = "site1"
            ansible_python_interpreter  = "/usr/bin/python3"

            ansible_ssh_user            = "terraform"
            vm_domain                   = "domain.com"
            service_role                = "infra-virt"
            squad                       = "data-squad"
            squad_alert_receiver        = "ata-squad"
            squad_cost_center           = "bare-metal-squad"
            squad_maintainer            = "data-squad"
            access_hostgroup            = "data-squad"
            }
        
    
}
```

then I am attempting to initialize the default varibles in common/defaults.hcl:

```
terraform {
    source = "git::placeholder"
}


locals {
    environment_vars = read_terragrunt_config(find_in_parent_folders("/prod/site2/113_site2_netbox_devices/pc1.hcl"))
}

inputs = {
    devices = [
    {        
        name                            = "null"
        description                     = "${local.environment_vars.locals.description}"
        device_type_id                  = 74 
        role_id                         = "${local.environment_vars.locals.role_id}"    
        site_id                         = "${local.environment_vars.locals.site_id}"    
        tags                            = "${local.environment_vars.locals.tags}"
        rack_id                         = "null"
        rack_face                       = "${local.environment_vars.locals.rack_face}"
        rack_position                   = "null"
        serial_number                   = "null"
        custom_fields = {
            env                         = "${local.environment_vars.locals.custom_fields.env}"
            consul_datacenter           = "${local.environment_vars.locals.custom_fields.consul_datacenter}"
            vm_provider                 = "${local.environment_vars.locals.custom_fields.vm_provider}"
            vm_name                     = "name"
            vm_ip                       = "0.0.0.0"
            vm_env                      = "prod"
            vm_site                     = "site2"
            vm_vpc                      = "site2"
            ansible_python_interpreter  = "/usr/bin/python3"
            ansible_host                = "null"
            ansible_ssh_host            = "null"
            ansible_ssh_user            = "terraform"
            vm_domain                   = "domain.com"
            service_role                = "infra-proxmox"
            squad                       = "infra-data-squad"
            squad_alert_receiver        = "infra-data-squad"
            squad_cost_center           = "infra-bare-metal-squad"
            squad_maintainer            = "infra-data-squad"
            access_hostgroup            = "infra-data-squad"
            }
    }
    ]
}
```

I also attempted to copy the contents of defaults.hcl to env.tfvars and the upper terragrunt.hcl but they seem to have the same behavior. My latests thought is that I might be passing the variables without de-encapsulting correctly.

One other thing I tried was adding this to the site2/terragrunt.hcl I created:

```
locals {
    environment_vars = read_terragrunt_config(find_in_parent_folders("/prod/site2/113_site2_netbox_devices/pc1.hcl"))
}

inputs = merge(
    local.environment_vars.locals,
)
```

I was using this example as base: https://github.com/gruntwork-io/terragrunt-infrastructure-live-example

The error I am getting from`terraform plan` is

```
 Error: Invalid value for input variable
│ 
│   on variables.tf line 31:
│   31: variable "devices" {
│ 
│ Unsuitable value for var.devices set using the TF_VAR_devices environment
│ variable: element 0: attributes "device_type_id", "role_id", and "site_id"
│ are required.
╵
ERRO[0001] Terraform invocation failed in /summarized/prod/site2/113_site2_netbox_devices/.terragrunt-cache/NBmhSDSSmJX9S9cGUmo_2NtZER0/TKgpFxsQFIDeExQSPe4nzSoRw-I  prefix=[/summarized/prod/site2/113_site2_netbox_devices] 
ERRO[0001] 1 error occurred:
        * [/summarized/prod/site2/113_site2_netbox_devices/.terragrunt-cache/NBmhSDSSmJX9S9cGUmo_2NtZER0/TKgpFxsQFIDeExQSPe4nzSoRw-I] exit status 1
```

The error goes away if I manually enter all the required variables in the deepest terragrunt.hcl for site 2 -- but I am not able to have it take the "default values" instead. It seems that the configuration imports are working but I am not able to find where my variable overrides are ending up.

Any help would be appreciated.